# Property is missing in null or undefined in Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am using Flow with React and I have a class that uses State and Props types like below:

```
type B = {x:number}

type State = {
  a: ?B
};

type Props = {}

class MyClass extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: null,
    };
  }
...
myFunction=()=>{

console.log(this.state.a.x)// Flow error here

}

}
```

The Flow error is: Cannot get `this.state.a.x` because property `x` is missing in undefined. What is the problem with my type definition? Why should I use 'Props' type definition in my constructor(props: Props) {} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?B` means that the `a` property the same as `B | null | void`. Since you can'd do `null.x` or `undefined.x` Flow is throwing a valid exception. To get your code to work you could for instance change

```
console.log(this.state.a.x);
```

to be

```
console.log(this.state.a ? this.state.a.x : null);
```

so that if `a` has not been set to a `B` value, it will log `null`.

Alternatively you could make the type `a: B`, but then you'd need to have a `B` value to put in the state as an initial value, and it sounds like you may not have that, since your example state sets `a: null`.

Comment: Do I need to change the code because of Flow? Because this.state.a is going to be initialized before the console.log. So it never becomes null in this function.

Comment: Flow has no way to know that. When using Flow it is up to you to design your datatypes in a way that allows Flow to statically analyze the types of things. You've declared the type as `?B` so Flow is doing just what you've told it to.